# Ubuntu without mouse

Tags: linux, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, mouse

Is it possible to steer the cursor with the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Check out the link below for a full tutorial:
[ubuntu: arrow keys make mouse pointer to move around](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/05/10/ubuntu-arrow-keys-make-mouse-pointer-to-move-around/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Go into System, Preferences, Assistive Technologies, Keyboard accessibility, Mouse Keys. Then select "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad